# CakePHP 3.x and datetimepicker

Tags: forms, cakephp, time, datetimepicker

I am using https://github.com/xdan/datetimepicker to select a date in my add function. Works like a charm. Now when I want to edit it - it inputs a weird date.

Custom Changes:
**bootstrap.php**

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Berlin');
```

**edit.ctp**

```
echo $this->Form->input('datetime', ['label' => __('Datum'), 'type'=>'text','id' => 'datetimepicker','selected' => '0000-00-00 00:00:00']);
```

**datetimepicker**

```
$('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
format:'Y-m-d H:i',
lang: 'de'
});
```

**Output in my view:**

```
<input type="text" name="datetime" id="datetimepicker" value="16.10.19 15:00">
```

**debug Output from my edit view**

```
'datetime' => object(Cake\I18n\FrozenTime) {

        'time' => '2019-10-16T15:00:00+02:00',
        'timezone' => 'Europe/Berlin',
        'fixedNowTime' => false

    }
```

Change the date_default_timezone_set already to UTC. But this doesn´t help. I wonder where my app gets the idea from putting this in my output. When I select it with my dtp again and choose a date it also works - but it takes a random date like 2019-10-10 and you have to go all the way back, which is quite inconvenient :/

Any ideas?

**EDIT**

I added this in my edit() function before I patched the Entity and it workd.

```
$adress['datetime'] = $adress['datetime']->i18nFormat('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just set the server timezone using **date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Berlin');** But **JavaScript** doesn't care about server timezone, if you doesn't set. **JavaScript** always try to use your PC time. **So**, You need to set **datetimepicker** timezone using **JavaScript**, if **datetimepicker** have the timezone option.

***OR***

Try to change your ***edit.ctp*** Code like below -

```
echo $this->Form->input(
 'datetime',
 [
  'label' => __('Datum'),
  'type'=>'text',
  'id' => 'datetimepicker',
  'default' => date('Y-m-d H:i') #Set time for today
 ]
);
```

Comment: That would help, but because I already have set an datetime when I added it, this won´t work :/ I edited the question. I found a solution which worked (in my edit function)

Comment: Ahh! Thank you @Isengo

Answer (score 0):

I added this in my edit() function before I patched the Entity and it works now. Hope this will help others. If somebody knows a better way, please share! I think this is just a workaround.

```
$adress['datetime'] = $adress['datetime']->i18nFormat('yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm');
```